# ClassCastException cannot cast to same class, possible classloader problem?

Tags: java, classloader, classcastexception

I have the following error message in my stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey
at myorg.blockchain.axr.util.FabricCA.loadSDKUser(FabricCA.java:90)
at myorg.blockchain.axr.core.Platform.init(Platform.java:91)
... 115 more
```

The line in question is referring to the last line of the following code snippet:

```
String keyPass = decryptPassword(appUserKeyPassword, appUserName, appUserAffiliation, appUserMspId);
// read and parse the encrypted private key PEM
pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(appUserKeyPath)));
PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encPrivKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
InputDecryptorProvider pkcs8Prov = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(keyPass.toCharArray());
BCECPrivateKey privKey = (BCECPrivateKey)converter.getPrivateKey(encPrivKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8Prov));
```

I looked up this exception and all of them refer to some sort of class loader problem. Is this question similar to the other class loader problems as well? How should I go about debugging this?

---

EDIT: This piece of code is developed standalone, but when integrated into the parent application it will be run in Tomcat. Not sure if this addresses the "running in a container" question?

Comment: It is highly likely that you have two instances of the `Class` loaded via different classloaders.  Not an easy problem to debug.  I assume you're in a web container of some sort.

Comment: I agree it looks like a classloader issue, in that the classloader that has loaded `BCECPrivateKey` in your code is not the same one that has loaded `BCECPrivateKey`  for use by the BouncyCastle library.  Where the configuration error is, though, is difficult to help you find with what you've given as it's usually dependent on environment, configuration, etc.  Are you in an OSGi container of some sort?  You can often set a breakpoint and inspect `getClass().getClassLoader()` for the two classes, which might indicate how the loading is happening.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the purpose of the code @JimGarrison

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the purpose of the code @MarkPeters